# VLC control set resource Uri as media in player C#\WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, libvlc

I want to play videos in `VlcControl` from my Assembly resources. I have a code:

```
 private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     var d = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
     d.Multiselect = false;
     if (d.ShowDialog() == true)
     {
        Uri src = new Uri(d.FileName);
        Player.MediaPlayer.Play(src);
     }
 }
```

How to change that worked with resource files, like code below:

```
 private void StartButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    // Change file Uri to resource Uri HERE!!!
    Uri src = new Uri(@"pack://application:,,,/MyAssemblyName;component/media/myVideo.mp4");
    Player.MediaPlayer.Play(src);
 }
```

Or create `Media` type from `ResourceStream` or any other way to achieve result... Tnx.

Comment: I think it is not a good idea to load file from memory. Why do you want to load file from memory? why not set Build action as copy to output and play as is.

Comment: @Mujahid Daud Khan, Because I need to hide file from the user.

Comment: @SkyDancer you can try use this approach http://stackoverflow.com/a/32026471/1480104